# Logstash 7.1.0 Cannot start as service RHEL 7

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I just installed logstash 7.1.0 from an RPM with `sudo yum install logstash.7.1.0.rpm`
system has 32 GB RAM.

When im trying to run the service as

```
[root@elk02 ~]# sudo systemctl start logstash
Failed to start logstash.service: Unit not found.

[root@elk02 ~]# java -version
java version "1.8.0_231"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)

[root@elk02 ~]# sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/system-install /etc/logstash/startup.options systemd
could not find java; set JAVA_HOME or ensure java is in PATH

[root@elk02 ~]$ cat .bash_profile
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_231
export JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_231/jre
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

Why am i getting the above two errors? How do i fix this?

Comment: Try to set the variable `JAVACMD` in the file `/etc/logstash/startup.options` pointing to the java binary, something like `JAVACMD=/opt/jdk1.8.0_231/bin/java` and run the `system-install` script again.

Comment: Hi @leandrojmp, i have made the above change but no change. Im still getting the java error. Kindly suggest what i can do further.

Comment: Try to export `JAVA_HOME ` in the cli before you run `system-install`, you are already as root, don't need to use sudo.

Comment: Added JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk to the startup.options and its working fine! Thanks @leandrojmp for the leads :)